# При вставке любого тега, текст переходит на следующую строку React

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, reactjs, jsx

Может я что-то упустил и не понял, но, что я только не делал. Я сделал текстовый редактор на сайте в котором есть 2 экрана, это ввод текста и вывод (предпросмотр) статьи. У меня есть несколько кнопок, которые стилизуют этот текст(теги заголовка, жирный, курсив, подчеркнутый). Весь текст обвёрнут в параграф (p) и редактируется отлично. Но когда я добавляю тег заголовка, например h1, то всё, что я стилизую после этого, переносится на следующую строку. То есть до заголовка я применял теги и они работали, но после добавления h1 (или любой другой тег заголовка), теги которые я использую, приобретают перенос текста.
Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, меня поймёт и, надеюсь, поможет :)

Comment: написано как-то не очень понятно, в вы бы код показали

но такой вопрос - посмотрите хотя бы в консоли разработчика (F12) браузера - а не получается ли у вас так, что форматирование обёрнуто тегом `<div></div>` или в обертке `<h1></h1>` добавлен стиль `display: block`

т.е. не происходит ли такое - вместо `<b>жирный</b> обычный` ставится `<div><b>жирный</b></div>обычный`

Comment: h1 вроде бы блочный по умолчанию. Конечно, после него будут элементы на новой строке.